# logstash could not be started when running multiple instances - path.data setting

Tags: logstash

Hi i am new to the internals of ELK stack

running a logstash process in background, and when it got picked up the matching file pattern, it says as in below

i want to understand here what is the importance of `path.data` option, Please help me out

```
[FATAL][logstash.runner] Logstash could not be started because there is already another instance using the configured data directory. If you wish to run multiple instances, you must change the "path.data" setting.
```

Comment: also i would like to understand the relation between path.data and sincedb

Comment: can you check my answer please?

Answer (score 11):

`path.data` directory is used by Logstash and its plugins for any persistent needs to store data, and it need to be different for each instance you are running, since Logstash does not allow multiple instances to share the same `path.data`.

By default its value is set to, `LOGSTASH_HOME/data`, which, under debian and rpm is `/usr/share/logstash/data`, and it is automatically assigned to first logstash instance unless explicitly specified.

If you want to run multiple logstash instances, you need to define the `path.data` either by command,

```
bin/logstash -f <config_file.conf> --path.data PATH
```

(make sure the directory is writable)

or specify in `logstash.yml` file under `/etc/logstash/` for each instance.

Answer (score 3):

That means you have two Logstash instances running and they cannot share the same data directory. You either need to kill the other instance or if you really want to have two instances running, you need to configure them to have different data directories.

Inside `logstash.yml`, you need to change the [`path.data`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-settings-file.html) setting for each instance.

Comment: sorry but can you explain it little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

IF someone just learning logstash and playing with plugins like grok and so on  the below commands are useful.

1 - list logstash processes by

`ps ax | grep logsta`

2 - find PID ( 4428 pts/5    Tl+    1:32 /usr/share/logstash/jdk/bin/java -Xm...)

3 - kill it
`sudo kill -9 4428`

4 - monitor logstash filter result by

`cd /usr/share/logstash/bin && sudo ./logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf`