# How can I send logs from file to Elasticsearch using Logstash between two separated servers?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, nosql, logstash, ubuntu-14.04

I try to send logs from `logs.csv` file to elasticsearch using Logstash. In Elasticsearch I have index logs with type log. At the moment my `logstash.conf` looks in this way:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/run/shm/elastic/logstash/logs.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      columns => ["logs"]
  }

}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "hostaddress:9200"
        index => "logs"
        document_type => "log"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "elastic"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

Logstash seems to be configured correctly because for instance `sudo ./logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'` works properly.
However I get error shown below. Any ideas?

```
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs errors to the console
[WARN ] 2018-07-11 10:48:27.473 [LogStash::Runner] multilocal - Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[FATAL] 2018-07-11 10:48:27.510 [LogStash::Runner] runner - Logstash could not be started because there is already another instance using the configured data directory.  If you wish to run multiple instances, you must change the "path.data" setting.
[ERROR] 2018-07-11 10:48:27.522 [LogStash::Runner] Logstash - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

Comment: how does your 'csv' file looks like?

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because another instance of Logstash is still running. You should start Logstash as a service in Linux instead of directly starting it, for example on RHEL you should start using:

```
service logstash start
```

and stop

```
service logstash stop
```

You can find commands for other systems under this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash.html).

But sometimes Logstash gets stalled and you have to kill it manually

```
ps aux | grep logstash
```

Find Logstash's PID and kill it:

```
kill -9 LOGSTASH_PID
```

Most of the time Logstash can't be stopped in the standard way because it's processing some data but you can force Logstash to stop by adding `--pipeline.unsafe_shutdown` in the service startup file, you can read more about this [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/shutdown.html#shutdown-stall-example).

Comment: I tried before `systemctl stop logstash`, `initctl stop logstash`, `/etc/init.d/logstash stop` and `ps -aux | grep logstash` with `kill -TERM {logstash_pid}` but nothing helped. Any other idea?

Comment: Kill all processes that `aimops` user possesses.

Comment: Does your process of logstash looks in this way `root     40279 20.1  0.5 13112228 915724 pts/5 Sl+  13:07   4:04 /usr/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true -Djruby.jit.threshold=0 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -cp /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/commons-compiler-3.0.8.jar:/usr/share/logstash/logstash- ...`?

Comment: What version of Logstash are you running? You can check it by running  `./logstash --version`.

Comment: I use version 6.3.1. I killed this process and it seems to be working fine however I have still problem with adding data from file with logs to elasticsearch. Do you have an idea why it adds only name of column instead of all logs from this column?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run multiple logstash instances, you need to define the `path.data` either by command,

```
bin/logstash -f <config_file.conf> --path.data PATH
```

(make sure the directory is writable)

or specify in `logstash.yml` file under `/etc/logstash/` for each instance.

Please read, [logstash could not be started when running multiple instances - path.data setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086824/logstash-could-not-be-started-when-running-multiple-instances-path-data-settin/51093532#51093532)

To read all columns fro  `csv` file, you need to provide name of each column like this,

```
columns => ["Date","column2","column3"]
```

Comment: I have provided name of the column `columns => ["logs"]` in my source code but it doesn't work. I have only one column `logs` and my logs below it. My file doesn't have to be in this format. If it is easier to have only logs in my file without column name it is also ok. Do you have an idea how can I send these logs to elasticsearch?

Comment: what was the issue?